# What happens to a bounty given to an answer later unaccepted?

Tags: discussion, bounties

What happens to a bounty if it's awarded to an accepted answer that is later unaccepted? Will the awarded value be reduced from the owner of that answer?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “unmarked as an answer”?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I guess by that they mean "unaccepted the answer".

Comment: @M.A.Ramezani: So do I, but given the choice of words, I am not so sure.

Comment: Unaccepted (: ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bounties, once awarded, are not reduced or removed. Only *developers* can remove already awarded bounties (not even moderators can do this).

The answer being accepted has no influence here; at most the answerer will lose the 15 points that comes with an accept.

Answer (score 3):

Bounties can never be rescinded once they've been awarded.  (Well, not by regular users anyway, a mod could remove it if it was used as a part of voting fraud.)  Only the 15 rep from the acceptance would be removed.

Answer (score 3):

**Nothing**, bounty are completely different from reputation given by up/down votes and mark as answered. Here is the cite from the [help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty):

> All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances.

And if the answer is unmarked as accepted, then the author of the answer will lose [15 points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) (and acceptor will lose 2 points).

Comment: The help center quote refers to the user who started the bounty, not the user who won the bounty, so not relevant to this question.